# Replace some values with a string in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column "Country" in a data frame, I would like to group the "Country" column with only two options: "Mainland China" and " Others". I have tried different options e.g. filter, etc. No one works. How should I do it?

Here is the dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/17DY8f-Jxba0Ky5iOUQqEZehhoWNO3vzR/view?usp=sharing

FYI, I have already grouped different provinces in China as one country "Mainland China"

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: can you post the data as code please, not a picture

Comment: one min, I will do it

Comment: interesting dataset

Comment: Do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, [mcve]. This seems rather basic, have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Oh, and this is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column.

Answer (score 3):

I think the quickest way to change the value would be using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead of `apply` since `.loc` is optimized for `pandas`.

```
df.loc[df.Country != 'Mainland China', 'Country'] = 'Others'
```

Comment: Thanks aws_apprentice! I tried that way. But apparently,  I made some mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Try (and group by `Country`):

```py
import numpy as np

df["Country"]=np.where(df["Country"].eq("Mainland China"), "Mainland China", "Other")
```

**Edit**

`timeit` (please note I didn't do `.loc[]` as `lambda doesn't support assignment` - feel free to suggest a way of adding it):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
from timeit import Timer

#proportion-wise that's the dataframe, as per OP's question

df=pd.DataFrame({"Country": ["Mainland China"]*398+["a", "b","c"]*124})

df["otherCol"]=2
df["otherCol2"]=3

#shuffle

df2=df.copy().sample(frac=1)
df3=df2.copy()
df4=df3.copy()

op2=Timer(lambda: np.where(df2["Country"].eq("Mainland China"), "Mainland China", "Other"))
op3=Timer(lambda: df3.Country.map(lambda x: x if x == 'Mainland China' else 'Others'))
op4=Timer(lambda: df4["Country"].apply(lambda x: x if x == "Mainland China" else "Others"))

print(op2.timeit(number=1000))
print(op3.timeit(number=1000))
print(op4.timeit(number=1000))
```

Returns:

```py
2.1856687490362674 #numpy
2.2388894270407036 #map
2.4437739049317315 #apply
```

Comment: Thanks Grazegorz, even though your solution comes later than those two guys, I know one way extra solving this problem. Thank you :D

Comment: No worries- time them - you will have some criteria to compare ;) I would expect ```np.where``` to be a bit faster than ```.loc[...]``` ```.apply(...)``` is outside of competition here.

Comment: What is the advantage of using this over `.loc[]`, aside from a tiny performance gain?

Comment: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173785/5082048, performance might be lower than for `.map(lambda x: ...)` for small datasets. List comprehensions scored best in that benchmark.

Comment: I benchmarked all the methods except ```.loc[]``` - please see above.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I just see it. Great to know. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, take your well deserved upvote! For benchmarking loc: what about defining two functions: The first just copies the dataframe. The second copies it, then assigns the column. The time of executing the `loc`statement would be the difference between the two. Also, out of interest, do you also want to add the list comprehension method?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `apply`:

```py
dataframe["Country"] = dataframe["Country"].apply(lambda x: x if x == "Mainland China" else "Others")
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works perfectly as well. Since I have already accepted one solution, I sincerely appreciate your help !

Comment: @AMC Thanks for involving in the discussion! I suppose that we should respect everybody's efforts. What do you think :)

Comment: @almo I agree entirely, my statement was in no way related to the answerer’s person or character.

Comment: @AMC on the plus side, it is quite flexible if other categories need to be defined in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming df is your pandas dataframe.

You could do:

```
df['Country'] = df.Country.map(lambda x: x if x == 'Mainland China' else 'Others')
```

Comment: Thanks,  perfect:D. I have wasted nearly one hour.

Comment: @AMC on the plus side, it is quite flexible if other categories need to be defined in the future.

Comment: @ArcoBast You could just use `.map()` and a dictionary, which is likely the most flexible solution.

Comment: @AMC I thought about this, but mapping everything except 'Mainland China' to a single value is not straightforward with a dictionary. I could have suggested using a defaultdict, of course, but considered that to be overkill. From an analyst's point of view, when working with a small dataset like this one, flexibility beats speed in my experience.

Comment: @ArcoBast It's certainly a unique situation, yes. For this particular case, I like the solution using `.loc[]`. As soon as the number of values to map changes, I prefer `.map()` with a dict.

Comment: I think the fact that the changes are being made on the same column does have an effect.